# How to run auto feed with a auto link for every created node?

Tags: rules, uri, feeds

I'm stuck on changing the url of a feeds

what i want to do is after a person creates a content
that feeds runs his feeds to the target url depending on
the value he filled in.

example:
person fills in "hello world" saves the content
the feeds will go to www.domain.com/hello%20world and does his thing.

i already setup the rules that after creating content type event
and the action execute feeds importer (so he runs the feeds)
only problem is it will only go to the already filled in url
instead of the one depending on what the person filled in

can anyone help me with this. Thx